# Flutter firebase add a similar field in all data

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection called span which has a field 'qty'. i want to add all the qty field in the data.
I am querying my data from firebase as follows

```
getsubtask() async {
    return Firestore.instance.collection('span').where('projectid',isEqualTo: widget.detailDocument.documentID).snapshots();
  }
```

So i need to add all the qty fields in the data i get from above list

```
int getTotals ;
  void getTotal() {
    for (int i = 0; i < getsubtask().length; i++)
      getTotals += getsubtask()[i]['qty'];
  }
```

I am trying this to get the total of qty field

```
  ListTile(
            title: Text(getTotals.toString()),
            leading: Text('qty'),
          ),
```

I am displaying the above data in listtile.

But it says "null" in the title when run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few problems in your code, mostly because data is loaded asynchronously and you'll need to handle that consistently. Some of the problems I quickly spotted:

1. `getsubtask()` is async, so you need to `await` its result when you call it.
2. This means that `getTotal` also needs to be `async`.
3. This in turn means that you can't call it like you do in your rendering code, but you'll need to use a `StreamBuilder` or store the total in the state.

```
  void getTotal() async {
    var subtasks = await getsubtask();
    var totals = ;
    for (int i = 0; i < subtasks.length; i++)
      totals += subtasks[i]['qty'];
    }
    setState({ totals: totals });
  }
```

Now you can call `getTotal()` in your constructor, or pretty much anywhere, to start calculating the total and then render the total with:

```
  ListTile(
    title: Text(totals),
    leading: Text('qty'),
  ),
```